Differences between transform_to(AltAz) between Astropy versions 4.0 and 5.3.1
I am trying to do the transfomation from ITRS to topocentric AltAz frame using SkyCoord.transform_to() functionality:
altazCoord = itrsCoord.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=time, location=obsGeoLocation)

The problem encountered is that under Astropy version 4.0 we are receiving different values than under Astropy version 5.3.1. Based on external validator we know that the values from version 4.0 are correct. I assume that some correction or some parts of the transformation was omitted in version 5.3.1 or replaced by other function. Can somebody suggest, what should be added to have equal values under astropy 5.3.1 in comparison to version 4.0?
Example outputs:
Current values - Astropy version 5.3.1
<SkyCoord (AltAz: obstime=60573.003523216925, location=(4053731.93746628, 1260550.54234471, 4744894.08614764) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt, distance) in (deg, deg, m)
    (169.68730146, 67.35702581, 23624164.67230157)>

Expected correct values - Astropy version 4.0
<SkyCoord (AltAz: obstime=60573.003523216925, location=(4053731.93746628, 1260550.54234471, 4744894.08614764) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt, distance) in (deg, deg, m)
    (169.68410928, 67.35684178, 23624155.6380583)>

EDIT1:
Reproducible example:
Here is reproducible example:
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, SkyCoord, AltAz
from astropy.time import Time
import astropy.units as u

time = Time(60573.003523216925, format='mjd', scale='utc')

itrsCoord = SkyCoord(x=23787247.15570922, y=9102499.0451817, z=15098296.92876073, unit='m',
                     representation_type='cartesian', frame='itrs', obstime=time)

obsGeoLocation = EarthLocation(lat=48.372528 * u.deg, lon=17.2736306 * u.deg, height=536.1 * u.m)

altazCoord = itrsCoord.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=time, location=obsGeoLocation))

print(altazCoord)

Today I ran the code with Astropy==6.1.4 with the very same result as 5.3.1.

Can you make this into a minimal, reproducible example? It's hard for me to test since I don't know what itrsCoord is. Also, are you able to try this using the latest version of Astropy, 6.1? If the problem persists in the latest version I would recommend raising this as an issue on the Astropy GitHub since they're more equipped to help you there.

@RoySmart - example added and also the code was executed with the latest Astropy version with same result as version 5.3.1.

Under AstroPy 4.3.1, I get the same results as for Astropy 5 and 6. For AstroPy 4.2.1, I get the results you see for AstroPy 4.0. So the change is in AstroPy 4.3.
Checking the release notes for AstroPy 4.3 (*), the first item is

Transformations to AltAz are now much more precise (and faster)

and the paragraphs read

Following advice from M. K. Brewer and comparisons with accurate
verification samples, the implementations for the transformations to
AltAz coordinates were made much more precise (down to the
milli-arcsec level). To help this, the CIRS frame has gained an
observer location attribute.
Furthermore, by ensuring expensive calculations of the
precession-nutation matrix are only done once, the transformations
have been sped up considerably.

This is the likely cause of the discrepancy you are seeing. Unfortunately, I can't offer a solution yet.

(*) AstroPy's website itself links to archive.org; apparently, they don't keep the release notes themselves on the website. Possibly in their GitHub repository, in a less readable format.

Just to provide the answer also here. Thanks to Astropy github community we came to the workaround. The code rewritten in the way bellow now works sufficiently also with newer Astropy versions:
itrsCoord = SkyCoord(x=23787247.15570922 * u.m - obsGeoLocation.x, 
                     y=9102499.0451817 * u.m - obsGeoLocation.y, 
                     z=15098296.92876073 * u.m - obsGeoLocation.z,
                     location=obsGeoLocation, 
                     representation_type='cartesian',frame='itrs', 
                     obstime=time)

Astropy community answer:
"Okay, fortunately astropy 5.2 introduced topocentric ITRS frames, which allows one to handle stellar aberration in the way you need. You need to subtract the observer ITRS coordinates from the object ITRS coordinates, and then load the difference into a topocentric ITRS frame for the observer. This procedure is described in the docstring for the ITRS frame."
Thank you very much for help.
